# Why is RSpec giving a NoMethodError when method exists?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm getting the error below

```
$ bundle exec rspec calculatorcli_spec.rb

 Failure/Error: c = CalculatorCLI.parse

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `parse' for CalculatorCLI:Class
```

from the below simple calculator class

[image: image of the code]

Answer (score 0):

`CalculatorCLI` is a class, and you're missing its initialization

either change `CalculatorCLI.parse` to CalculatorCLI.new.parse`or change`def parse`to`def self.parse`in`CalculatorCLI` definition

Comment: thank you that worked. I missed the instantiation doh!